# Why does freeing my reallocated array fail in C?

Tags: c, arrays

This seems to reallocate fine in the debugger (at least it doesn't fall into the error condition). When I call free, it yells "Heap corruption detected!" Any idea why?

```
int arri_init(ARRAY_INT *a, const int intSize)
{
    a->array = NULL;
    a->size = 0;

    a->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * intSize);
    if (a->array == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    a->size = intSize;

    return TRUE;
}
int arri_resize(ARRAY_INT *a, const int intNewSize)
{
    int *temp = NULL;

    // Get a temporary variable
    temp = a->array;

    // Reallocate array
    a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, intNewSize);
    if (a->array == NULL)
    {
        a->array = temp;
        return FALSE;
    }

    a->size = intNewSize;

    return TRUE;
}


void arri_release(ARRAY_INT *a)
{
    if (a->array)
    {
        free(a->array);
        a->array = NULL;
    }
}
```

// Main code

```
int main(void)
{
    ARRAY_INT a;

    arri_init(&a, 10);
    arri_resize(&a, 20);

    a.array[13] = 5;

    printf("%d\n", a.array[13]);

    arri_release(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `intNewSize` in terms of number of bytes (i.e. premultiplied with `sizeof(int)`), or number of array elements?

Comment: It's just a new size number.

Comment: Odds are pretty good that something is writing beyond the end of an allocated block and clobbering a magic number that the memory allocator uses to make sure the heap is intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initially allocate `a->array` with `sizeof(int) * intSize`, but when you resize the array, you reallocate it using `intNewSize` only, meaning your reallocated size is going to be off by a factor of `sizeof(int)`. Instead, it should be `realloc(a->array, sizeof(int) * intNewSize)`

In your `main` method, your `arri_resize(&a, 20)` call would result in a reallocation of only 20 bytes, which is only 5 integers (assuming 32-bit integers). Thus, when you write to index number 13, you shoot right past the end of the array's storage space.

Comment: Oh, duh. I figured it was something stupid. Thanks, it worked.